# Meaning of "My heart went on my stomach."

Tags: sentence-meaning

I heard this sentence in a speech today.

> My heart went on my stomach.

The context is that she realized that her mother might have died from an accident. Then she said that sentence.

I searched it on the web, and I only get a similar one "[My heart fell into my stomach](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=A0LEVxb.PBpaERUA2RFXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEyYWRxOG04BGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwM3BHZ0aWQDQjQ5ODJfMQRzZWMDc3I-?qid=20091206184733AAh0LaH&p=heart%20went%20to%20stomach%20meaning)."

What does it mean in this context?  Is it another way of saying "my heart fell into my stomach"?

Comment: Your analysis is probably correct. The sentence is ungrammatical, anyway. It should be *went **to***. Is English the speaker's first language?

Comment: @Mick, yes, it's from a native speaker. I might not hear it exactly because my listening is not as good as natives. What would natives likely to say in this case?

Comment: "My heart sank to [the pit of] my stomach" would be more colloquial.